# file in matlab workspace

Tags: matlab, file, types

I studied a program related to my work in which I have a file named `vhf_power_0510`, when I loaded this file, then in matlab workspace it appears as: **note here** that I write square brackets and equal sign only to make clear what is written in workspace :

```
 [Name=pwr value=1800×10×267 double Min=<Too many elements> Max=<Too many elements>]
```

In program after that when they write in command window, `lgtime=length(pwr(:,1,1))`

Then in workspace it appears as: *note that here I again write square brackets and equal sign only to make clear what is written in workspace

```
 [Name=lgtime value=1800 Min=1800 Max=1800]
```

My problem is that I don't understand **pwr** is which type of matrix or how this type of matrix is created and how I can open this file from workspace?Because in matlab workspace matrix has only m×n while there are 3 numbers 1800×10×267 double. Also when I double click to open pwr from workspace it does not open rather a sentence comes 'Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He file is a `3d matrix of 64 bits double` values. It is just loaded to your workspace. You can call it by its name. You can call a submatrix of it. For example,

```
pwr(1,1,1)
```

Or

```
pwr(1)
```

will print the first value of it.

Also, you can see submatrix of it:

```
a=pwr(:,:,1);
```

will give you a 2D matrix from pwr which has 1800x10 elements in it.

The workspace is showing up to 0.5 M pixel values for 3D+ matrices.